# extract all XML tags and values

Tags: linux, xml

I have this long line:

```
<hdr><name><first>John</first><mid></mid><last>Smith</last></name><dob>04181995</dob><phone>5550001111<phone></hdr>
```

how to extract just the following?

```
<first>John</first>
<mid></mid>
<last>Smith</last>
<dob>04181995</dob>
<phone>5550001111<phone>
```

tried sed but get extra tags:

```
echo "<hdr><name><first>John</first><mid></mid><last>Smith</last></name><dob>04181995</dob><phone>5550001111<phone></hdr>" | sed -e 's/></>\n</g'

<hdr>
<name>
<first>John</first>
<mid>
</mid>
<last>Smith</last>
</name>
<dob>04181995</dob>
<phone>5550001111<phone>
</hdr>
```

Perhaps grep can do it. I am lost. Please, help

Comment: You have error in XML, there is no close `phone` tag

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an XML parser like `xmllint` with XPath to navigate and select the nodes you need.

```
echo "<hdr><name><first>John</first><mid></mid><last>Smith</last></name><dob>04181995</dob><phone>5550001111</phone></hdr>" \
| xmllint --xpath 'hdr/name/* | hdr/dob | hdr/phone' -
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the XML parser `xmlstarlet` (and after fixing the broken `phone` end tag):

```bsh
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/hdr' -c 'name/*' -c dob -c phone -nl file.xml
<first>John</first><mid/><last>Smith</last><dob>04181995</dob><phone>5550001111</phone>
```

This first matches the `/hdr` node and then continues to pick out a copy (`-c`) of each child node of the `name` node, i.e., the `first`, `mid`, and `last` sub-nodes.  It then also extracts copies of the `dob` and `phone` nodes.