# extract XML tags and values

Tags: linux

[image]

Can it be done with sed or grep or awk?  please, help

Comment: what's wrong with the two answers on your previous question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683223/extract-all-xml-tags-and-values - is it because the two answers didn't use the wrong tools you want to use?

Comment: XHTML is *worse* than XML, but [t̸h̶i̷s̶ ̴S̶t̷a̶c̵k̵o̶̖̾̌̌̀͝v̵̥͍͕̻͉͓̏̇̈́̍̎͝ḛ̴̠̲̝͛̈́̏̇̓r̴͎̣̹͝f̶̨͕̤̉́̐͑͘͘ļ̶̞̾̅͝ó̵̤̮̙̓̈́͋ẁ̷̼͙̞̇̀͒ ̴͔̱͇͕̬͛́͜ȁ̶̮̟̭̬̺̅͛̕ṋ̸̢̲̱̰̹̈̅͜͝s̶̖͖̻̗͙̮̺͇͋̏͑̈́͌̾̅̔ͅẁ̸̧̳̜̰͑ͅè̴̢̧̧̡͕̺̞̣̼̗̈́̅͌̄͝r̸̛͈̟̼̱͒̀͗̕͜ ̶͉́̈̾͗̇m̴̛̫̟ĩ̶͙̓g̴̟͗̕h̸̘́t̷͈́̂͠ ̵̮̳̫̾͠b̸̧̞̆e̴̺̿͒ ̴̛̤̠̻̑̒r̷̦̖̂̕͘a̸͓̝̅̂͝t̸͇̀͆h̸̫͇͑e̶͔̐͝r̷̠̼̅͘ ̸͖́̇͑͜e̸̹͖͠ṇ̶́͗l̶͍̓̃́į̴̙̦̿̓̆g̴̻̽̇h̸̨̪̟͐͊t̴̗̟͙̚e̵̠͂nĭ̵̼n̷̮̍g̶̢̥̥̑̋̅̂͠](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4433386). All the same reasons apply here.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @roaima i figured that.  that's why i VTC as a dupe.   this one's not only a dupe, it's worse - it's an image of the text in the original.

Answer (score 1):

XML parsing cannot reliably be handled with either of `grep` or `sed`. The problem is that it's not a regular language so it cannot be parsed with regular expressions. It's conceivably possible with `awk`, but I don't know of anyone who's written an XML parser in `awk` when much better tools such as `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint` exist.

If you don't have these relatively standard XML parsing tools they are easy to install.